# Choosing the right number

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this code.

I try to make a C program that only scan no repetitive numbers but it doesn't work it a lot of times. That's the code:

```
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        //training for sorting tables
        int tab[100] , *p , n , bb=0 ;
        p=tab ;
        printf("enter how many numbers you want to type \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("enter the numbers one by one okay"); 
        for(int i=0; i<n ; i++)
        {
            printf("number %d \n", i+1);
            scanf("%d",*(p+i));
            for(int x=0 ; x<= i ; x++)
            {
                if(*(p+x) == *(p+n))
                {
                    bb=1;
                }
            }
            if (bb == 1)
            {
                i-- ;
            }
        }

        for(int a=0 ; a<n ; a++)
            printf("%d \n", *(p+a));
    }
```

Comment: Also, please fix your formatting. The code is really hard to read as is because the indentation is jumbled all over the place.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It should be `<stdio.h>` for standard IO

Comment: @Fuzxxi `ctype.h` is a C header. `cctype` is the C++ header of `ctype.h`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I know, but you'll need that for the `printf()` to work, right?

Comment: It would be better to say what you actually get (I guess that program crashes on first `scanf`, at least most of the time).

Comment: @SouravGhosh I only read the `#include <c...>` part and immediately thought “what? a C++ header?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to talk about the algorithm because that's not what you asked.

I see here 2 main problems. The firs is here:

```
scanf("%d",*(p+i));
```

`scanf` should get address of the parameter as the second argument. It should be `scanf("%d", p+i);`

The second one is the fact that you set your `bb` flag to 1 inside the `for` loop but then you never clear it.You can reset is here:

```
if (bb == 1)
{
    i--;
    bb = 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

As others mention in their answers. You also need to change

```
if(*(p+x) == *(p+n))
```

to

```
if(*(p+x) == *(p+i))
```

because you want to check for duplication until the **currently entered** number. Also the stop condition inside the `for` loop from

```
for(int x=0 ; x<= i ; x++)
```

to

```
for(int x=0 ; x<i ; x++)
```

since when `x==i` you will get `true` for `*(p+x) == *(p+i)`

**EDIT:** Just a notification.

In the following loop (as I understand it) you are looking for the same number

```
for(int x=0 ; x<i ; x++)
 {
     if(*(p+x) == *(p+i))
     {
         bb=1;
     }
 }
```

So once you found it there is no need to iterate to the end. You can either use `break` to break the inner loop:

```
for(int x=0 ; x<i ; x++)
 {
     if(*(p+x) == *(p+i))
     {
         bb=1;
         break;
     }
 }
```

Or add the `bb==0` condition to the `foor` loop stop condition:

```
 for(int x=0 ; x<i && bb==0 ; x++)
 {
     if(*(p+x) == *(p+i))
     {
         bb=1;
     }
 }
```

Moreover, you can drop this `bb` flag at all:

```
 int x;
 for(x=0 ; x<i && *(p+x)==*(p+i) ; x++);
```

and then just

```
 if (x < i)
 {
     i-- ;
 }
```

Comment: thnak you very much Mr alex a really appreciate your work if works know that god help you in your life have a good night

Answer (score 2):

The error is here:

```
scanf("%d",*(p+i));
```

That should be:

```
scanf("%d", p+i);
```

When you're scanning an integer, the argument should be the address of the integer variable to store in. You were indirecting through the address, passing the value of the integer itself (which isn't initialized yet).

Comment: thank you barmar I really appreciate your ambition have a good weekend

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing *(p+x) and *(p+n).  I believe you meant to compare *(p+x) and *(p+i).  And you really should write them p[x] and p[i] or even tab[x] and tab[i], since p doesn't seem to have a purpose here.

Comment: I think that using `*(p+x)` instead of `p[x]` helps the OP to understand that there are pointers involved and not arrays.